# getting mouse location without a listener

Tags: java, swing, mouse, css-position

In some situations I need to place a JFrame right where the mouse cursor is located. Do I really need a mouse listener to track mouse move events, or I can just read current mouse position somehow?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469515/java-mouse-motion-anywhere-on-screen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Mouse Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this could help:

`MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()`

Comment: Yes, you can use `myJFrame.setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());`