# how to automatically shutdown a system when it is not used for 2 minutes?

Tags: java, shutdown

how to shutdown a system when it is not used.
if a system is not used for a 2 minutes of time like not even used keyboard or mouse or any other applications in system. that system should be shut down.
how to make this one possible.

Comment: Your definition of "not used" is too vague. There are gauranteed to be applications running on any given system 100% of the time it's running. Could you narrow that down at all?

Comment: `System.exit(0);`

Comment: what type of `system` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Process** class allows you to run commands for windows/any OS from java below is snippet

```
Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s");
System.exit(0);
```

Place the above code in your logic and rest how you want that to invoke depends on your logic the way you want.

> **Note :** Here I am guessing by system you mean your OS. if you mean just
>   application then just **System.exit(0);** would suffice.

**EDIT :**

> As asked by OP to check the idle time, I think you need to implement
>   event listeners mostly mouse and keyboard. Below are some helpful
>   links to which will help you implement it in your program:

[Java mouse motion anywhere on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469515/java-mouse-motion-anywhere-on-screen)

[How can I listen for key presses (within Java Swing) across all components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344823/how-can-i-listen-for-key-presses-within-java-swing-across-all-components)

Approach for above is have a timer just when you record an event from keyboard or mouse reset the timer else shutdown.

Comment: does not answer *like not even used keyboard or mouse or any other applications in system*

Comment: LOL After a short delay I can tell you that this does indeed work from windows as well.

Comment: @ScaryWombat edited the answer to check idle time while not using keyboard or mouse.