# Java - Detect if mouse is pressed down anywhere on the screen

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, detect, awtrobot

I want my program to detect if the mouse is pressed down anywhere on the Screen and not just the program window. It should also detect when the mouse is being released. Is it possible in Java to detect this outside of my program window?

Comment: I'm not sure if it only works in your program but have you tried using a mousehandler

Comment: Yes! It's possible. You need to add a `MouseMotionListener` and listen for `mouseDragged` event

Comment: @Mohit your sure that `MouseMotionListener` also supports `MousePressed` and `MouseReleased`?

Comment: Does Mousemotionlistener work outside of the program window?

Comment: @AllesLegti Yes Mohit already set that the MouseMotionListener can be used outside the program

Comment: @AllesLegit What do you want to achieve?

Comment: *"anywhere on the Screen"* What is the business of your app. knowing what I click elsewhere on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener is only going to give you information about mouse movement inside your application window. For events that occur outside that window, there is no way around MouseInfo.getPointerInfo.
This is a duplicate of [Java mouse motion anywhere on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469515/java-mouse-motion-anywhere-on-screen).

Comment: I'm asking for mouse presses.... Look what this guy wrote: You will only receive mouseMoved events, never mouseDragged events. That's because there is no way to receive information about clicks outside the main window.

Comment: @AllesLegit try to use a `MouseListener` instead you can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)

Comment: @MartinŠpelina why don't you tell him that before? he wrote in his Question that he Needs a mousepressed and released

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should look at the [Java Native Hook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) for Global Mouse and Key Listeners